# failed password for installing homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I am trying to download homebrew but the default of terminal ask me type in password and I don't know exactly the password for that. Could anyone tell me how to deal with that?

```
    Last login: Sun Oct 27 17:32:17 on ttys000
`111-250-68-247:~ louisa$ ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
==> This script will install:
    /usr/local/bin/brew
    /usr/local/Library/...
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press ENTER to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir /usr/local

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir /usr/local
111-250-68-247:~ louisa$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's asking for the password of your account but it doesn't seem to be an authentication issue. You probably need to [enable the root account](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528)

Answer (score 0):

Use the password for the User that you are currently logged in as. Worked for me